# Getting data in daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

How to get the data of the startDate and endDate of the dateRangePicker?

This is my jquery below:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'center',
        showDropdowns : true,
        startDate : moment().subtract(1,'day'),
        endDate : moment().subtract(1,'day'),
        locale :{
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
        }
    }), function(start, end, label){
        window.alert("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }
    var yesterday = moment().subtract('day', 1);
    console.log(yesterday);
});
```

I'm trying to get the data so i can input it on my d3.js chart. But when I `console.log` the data of variable `yesterday` it's returning

```
 M {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: P, _d: Sun Apr 19 2020 10:47:09 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), …}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_locale: P {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_d: Sun Apr 19 2020 10:47:09 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time) {}
_isValid: true
__proto__: Object
```

I'm new to javascript and i thought it will show the same as the one in the daterangepicker:
[image: daterangepicker]

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with jQuery only:

```
$('#daterange').val()
```

There's no built-in way for that.

P.S.

1. The [source code](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/blob/3d57f7bd6f7f57dd115b3438353b1e3bfabb301f/daterangepicker.js) includes a property named `chosenLabel`, which apparently was intended to be used with calling `$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').chosenLabel`, but it's always undefined.
2. As I'm sure you'd need other examples, make sure you review the original [examples](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples).